# how to disable filelight showing snap applications?

Tags: ubuntu, snap

I'm using linux ubuntu 16-04, and filelight as my favourite tool to inspect disk usage.
Recently I installing some snap packages. I see them showed as different units on filelight:

[image: snap package as shown in filelight]

Does anybody have the same problem, and do you have any suggestion to disable this weird behaviour?

Comment: I think you will have to show us what is happening.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I added a small screenshot from the app

Comment: This question is still not clear: I see `snap` as the only directory/units showing. Different to what. There has to be at least 2 things in a difference (Something can not be different; what is it different to).

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude directories in Filelight by selecting the menu `Settings` > `Configure Filelight…`, then the first tab `Scanning`.

[image: Filelight screenshot]

Simply add the path to the snap packages here.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion: I've already tried to exclude the `/snap` item, as well as single packages, but it does not work for some reason: I continue seeing items such as `/snap/{item}/{item}`, listed as units.

Comment: I just tested it, and it works fine for me. How are you invoking Filelight exactly? On root? Is the screenshot above after you clicked through a few levels already? When you say you see `/snap/{item}/{item}`, are you implying that you *don't* see `/snap` itself?

Comment: yes I don't see `/snap` itself (but I tried excluding it explicitly), and I'm running the application as a normal user... you mean I should run it as root? Even if it would be weird, I've tested as weel and does not work

Comment: No, sorry, I mean on the root directory `/`. How precisely are you invoking the program? You launch Filelight, then click the `/`? Then immediately after that you see what? (Surely not the screenshot above?) Please edit your question and put in *precisely* what you do and see, and please don't miss anything out!

Answer (score 0):

Each snap is a separate filesystem that is mounted dynamically by the host operating system when the application is used. Apparently Filelight doesn't see the snaps as individual files but as separate filesystems. So:

- On the home screen: they are displayed as separate disks

  - It is what you see.
- When the `/snap` folder is scanned: except the `README` file, nothing is displayed.

  [image: /snap folder scan output]

Excluding the `/snap` folder from the scan in the Filelight settings does not change anything (the individual files are excluded, not the corresponding filesystems). Currently (17.12.3 for me), the is no way to exclude these "filesystems" from Filelight. Until a fix or a new configuration option, we have to live with unreadable main screens like that:

[image: Home screen when many snaps are installed]

I have more than 50 snaps installed. It's huge and unreadable...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and there is not an answer here yet. The last guys who said "I have more than 50 snaps installed. It's huge and unreadable..." is absolutely correct, it's really hard to read.

I have /snap/ excluded, yet this is what I get when I run filelight from CLI:

:~$ filelight
Found the following remote filesystems:  ()
Found the following local filesystems:  ("/run/", "/run/lock/", "/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/", "/snap/gimp/383/", "/snap/vlc/2288/", "/snap/core18/2344/", "/snap/bare/5/", "/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87/", "/snap/snapd/15177/", "/snap/snapd/14978/", "/snap/snap-store/547/", "/snap/gtk-common-themes/1515/", "/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4/", "/snap/core20/1361/", "/snap/vlc/2344/", "/snap/core20/1376/", "/snap/wire/233/", "/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/", "/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/", "/boot/efi/", "/snap/telegram-desktop/3544/", "/snap/gimp/380/", "/snap/telegram-desktop/3530/", "/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99/", "/snap/snap-store/558/", "/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/", "/snap/wire/237/", "/snap/core18/2284/", "/snap/android-file-transfer-linux/199/", "/snap/brave/150/", "/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/", "/run/user/119/", "/run/user/1000/", "/media/me/f167466e-2b5b-4d01-a0d3-1cc860105aba/", "/media/me/C0A8D308A8D2FBBA/", "/run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs/", "/run/snapd/ns/", "/snap/brave/151/")

So, each one of those snaps are found and displayed so there is a whole field of found disks, many more than I want to count.

Thank you for reading. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/409265)

Comment: Excuse me if I got something wrong here, that was my very first comment here. I wasn't trying to add a solution but was instead adding more information, which was in CLI, even though "/snap" was part of the excluded list, filelight still displays "/snap/*" with "Found the following local filesystems: ("/run/", "/run/lock/", "/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/", "/snap/gimp/383/", ...." I'm not rogue, just super new here. No harm was meant.

Comment: OK, nobody said that you intended harm.  But let’s try to use the correct terminology.  “Excuse me if I got something wrong …” was your first comment.  The problem is that you posted “I'm having the same problem ...” *as  an  **answer*** — you typed it into a text box labeled “Your Answer”.  And so let’s try to follow the rules: “I'm having the same problem ...” is not an answer, and should not be posted as one. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Unfortunately, [SE] is not very good at handling the case where a question languishes for years without receiving a satisfactory answer.  I recommend that you [post a new question](/questions/ask).  First thing, make it clearer than this one — I don’t understand what Alfredo Serafini is saying.  Try to format correctly (and capitalize correctly).  Then include your details.  Link to this question, and say what happened when you tried each of the solutions presented here.

Comment: Oh, I was unaware that I typed that into an answer box. My apologies. I will pay better attention moving forward. I am going to study this thread and see if I can post something that conveys the problem better in a new post.